# How Do I Make Office Application Open In Background

Tags: ms-access

I have a macro that runs in access (office 365) when it is opened. Once the macro runs, the application closes. What i am trying to figure out is if i can have the application run as described without seeing it flash on the screen. I have another application that is triggering the access file to run. So, it is autonomous. Any resources would be most helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: If you'd share how you're opening the file from that other application, we might be able to tell you how to adjust that to open Access in the background